# Saving the work done on a Ubuntu terminal through Sublime text

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, sublimetext3

Recently I carried out some work on the Linux Ubuntu terminal. In order to save the work(commands) for future reference I saved the entire terminal text on a document. Can I store that text in an extension other than '.txt' so as to get a similar color scheme when I view it through sublime text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. If you use '.sh', Sublime will automatically recognize the Bash commands when you open the file. Technically, though, you can use whatever file extension you like. You can always go to View > Syntax > Shell Script (Bash), to see Bash syntax highlighting on a file with a different file extension.